# Missing config.ru when using rackup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when running rackup command, the error message is shown:

```
[root@li608-165 ~]# rackup
configuration /root/config.ru not found
```

I just installed the Ruby on Rails.

System: Centos 6.5
Ruby: 1.9.3-p547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a file called `config.ru` to your `root/` directory.

`config.ru` is the configuration file for rackup, and controls what `rackup` will actually run.

Look at section 2.3 for an explanation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

> To use rackup instead of Rails' rails server, you can put the following inside config.ru of your Rails application's root directory:

```
# Rails.root/config.ru
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)

use Rails::Rack::Debugger
use Rack::ContentLength
run Rails.application
```

Comment: I'm sorry about that. You can post another question if you still need help. Otherwise if this answered your question, you can accept it. Please keep in mind stackoverflow isn't a debugging site, though. It's for specific problems that you have tried to solve yourself, but failed.