# Rails Server Keeps Exiting When Trying To Start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, server

I have had the local server going for the build-out of most of this app but I recently closed it and now I'm trying to start it back up but I'm getting this error?

`` => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
configuration /Users/intern/Desktop/Rails/Projects/tulip-time-texter/config.ru not found
Exiting ``

I've never seen this before. Any help would be great!

Comment: Does /Users/intern/Desktop/Rails/Projects/tulip-time-texter/config.ru exists? Maybe you deleted it?

Comment: I think I put it in gitingnore but it should still work right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456344/missing-config-ru-when-using-rackup

Comment: Hmmm.. I it looks like everything should be working but still getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that I placed my config.ru file in my .git file. It just needed to be placed back in the root directory.